# Play market in-app billing

Tags: java, php, android, finance

I want to add in-app purchases to my application. In-app in test mode works great, but there is no check on their authenticity. While googling some info about making server-side of in-app, I found out that server-side won't work correctly with test purchases.

Will this code work fine with real purchases or is there anything that won't work in production?

Client-side:

```
IabHelper mHelper;
public boolean billingworks=false;
String itemsku="Item name";
String AccLogin="Account name";

public void initBilling(){ //Is called inside onCreate
    String base64EncodedPublicKey = 
                                   "Public key from Google Play";

        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

        mHelper.startSetup(new 
        IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
             public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) 
         {
            if (result.isSuccess()){
            List additionalSkuList = new ArrayList();
            additionalSkuList.add(itemsku);
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkuList, mQueryFinishedListener);
             billingworks=true;} else
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"An error occurred with billing system.",1024).show();
         }
        });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    } else {

    }
}

public void buyItem(){
    if (billingworks){
mHelper.flagEndAsync();
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, itemsku, 10001,   
               mPurchaseFinishedListener, "Ejfjejf");
               toast("Trying to purchase...");
    } else
    Toast.makeText(this,"An error occurred. Try to restart",1024).show();
}

public void toast(String s){
    Toast.makeText(this,s,1024).show();
}

public String urlencode(String s){
    try{
    return URLEncoder.encode(s,"UTF-8");
    }catch(Exception e){return "none";}
}

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            toast("Error purchasing: "+result);
            return;}
        if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
            toast("Error purchasing. Authenticity verification failed.");
            return;
        }

        if (purchase.getSku().equals(itemsku)) {

            mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);

        }}};

IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() 
{
public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) 
{
    if (mHelper == null) return;
    if (result.isSuccess()) 
    {
        try{
        JSONObject checker=new JSONObject(purchase.getOriginalJson());
            toast("Activating account...");
            String url="http://mypage/check.php?login="+AccLogin+"&responsedata="+urlencode(purchase.getOriginalJson())+"&signature="+urlencode(purchase.getSignature());
            String[] verify=getPageS(url);
            if (verify.length>0) toast(verify[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){}
    } 
    else 
    {
        // handle error
    }
}
};

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener 
   mQueryFinishedListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
   public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory)   
   {
  if (result.isFailure()) {
     return;
   }

   Purchase p =
      inventory.getPurchase(itemsku);
      if (p!=null)
          mHelper.consumeAsync(p, mConsumeFinishedListener);

   }
};
```

Server-side:

```
$responseCode = 0;
$user = $_GET['login'];
$data = json_decode(urldecode($_GET['responsedata'],true)); 
$signature = urldecode($_GET['signature']); 
$publicKey = "Public key from GP"; 
$key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" . chunk_split($publicKey, 64, "\n") . "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"; 
$key = openssl_get_publickey($key); 
if (false === $key) { 
    exit("error openssl_get_publickey"); 
}

$result = openssl_verify($data, base64_decode($signature), $key); 
if ($result == 1) { 
//Activating account 
} elseif ($result == 0) { 
    echo "bad"; 
} else { 
    echo "error"; 
}
```

Comment: Do you know if this code works? Because submitting broken code is off topic here.

Comment: sounds to me like it works, but there is no way to test a specific aspect of the app in the test environment.  I would say it is on-topic.

Comment: Client-side part of this code works perfectly while server-side one tells me that I give wrong data. Is it true that server-side part doesn't work with test mode purchases?

Answer (score 1):

This is a big, big issue with your code: indentation.

It is excruciatingly difficult to read code that is poorly indented. Here is how indentation works:

- Everything starts without indentation
- Every time you create a code block (`{ [code] }`), another indentation is added.

Typically a single indentation is either 1 tab or 4 spaces. I use 1 tab.

For example, let's take this snippet from your code:

```
if (billingworks){
mHelper.flagEndAsync();
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, itemsku, 10001,   
               mPurchaseFinishedListener, "Ejfjejf");
               toast("Trying to purchase...");
    } else
    Toast.makeText(this,"An error occurred. Try to restart",1024).show();
```

Here is what it would look like with correct indentation:

```
if (billingworks) {
    mHelper.flagEndAsync();
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, itemsku, 10001,   
    mPurchaseFinishedListener, "Ejfjejf");
    toast("Trying to purchase...");
} else
    Toast.makeText(this,"An error occurred. Try to restart",1024).show();
```

I actually can see what this code is doing now.

---

Honestly, this code is so poorly indented that I'm not sure I can even continue the review; I don't want to give any false information based on my interpretation of what I can read of the code.

However, I will try to at least point a few more things out.

---

```
if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
} else {

}
```

Why is there an `else` statement? You have nothing in it, so there is no point in putting this here at all.

---

```
IabHelper mHelper;
public boolean billingworks=false;
String itemsku="Item name";
String AccLogin="Account name";
```

I don't this code is it; I am assuming that it is in a class.

If so, then these variables should all have scope identifiers, like the one that `billingworks` has.

However, going back to `billingworks`, I think you should make this a `private` field. Keeping this public could be a potential **security issue**. Also, from I am shown, you are only accessing `billingworks` from inside the class, so there is no point in letting it be access globally.

For the same reason as I just stated, I think the other fields should be private too.

*The reason why I say this could be a security issue is because this is going to be run on a client's side and it is handling billing and payment information. Someone might be able to manipulate the information if the field is public.*

---

Please, please go through your code and fix the indentation. I'm sure there is plenty more to review in this post.

Once you fix your code, post a follow up question and leave a comment to this answer; I will review the new one also.